# Spring SmartLifeCycle sequential behavior?

Tags: spring-boot, lifecycle

I have an application that is broken down into several modules.  I created a class whose job is to start them in the right order and give each module enough time to start.  I have messed with SmartLifeCycle quite a bit in the past but i would like to know more about how it would behave if i was to use it for my modules instead of needing a separate class that handles each modules's startups and shutdowns.

For example, module A takes quite a bit of time to start as it needs to initialize several TCP connections to other systems.  Module B is dependent on module A being fully initialized as it sends various messages to these clients.  If i make each module implement SmartLifeCycle and give them the correct phase so they start in the right order, can i assume that Spring will fully initialize one before moving to the next?  Do we have any control over this behavior?

Comment: Would pairing SmartLifeCycle with DependsOn help me achieve what i'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you please add some examples here referring modules? modules in the sense of different `@Component` in your project or totally separate spring-boot project?

Comment: I mean different components within the same project.  In my case I have for example a Connections module which initializes sockets with a bunch of servers.  The second module is Messaging which uses those sockets and sends messages depending on the user's actions.  There are a few more but essentially they are all in the same application and mostly depend on each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO it's better to use an event-driven way to control your "modules". If I understand you correctly in each modules you have some services which should do some job depending on each other. So in this case, you can publish the necessary events and implement some listeners that react to these events and call the correspond methods of those servers, then publish other events that trigger the next part of listeners, etc.

For example:

```java
@Component
public class FirstHandler {
    @Autoware private FirstService service;

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class) // start when App is ready
    public FirstWorkCompleted onAppReady() {
        service.doWork();
        return new FirstWorkCompleted(); // send FirstWorkCompleted event
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class SecondHandler {
    @Autoware private SecondService service;

    @EventListener(FirstWorkCompleted.class) // start when First work is completed
    public SecondWorkCompleted onFirstWorkCompleted() {
        service.doWork();
        return new SecondWorkCompleted(); // send SecondWorkCompleted event
    }
}
```

You can also send events with `ApplicationEventPublisher` - just inject it in your component.

`@EventListener` methods can work asynchronously - just add `@Async` annotation to such methods (don't forget to apply `@EnableAsync` annotation to your config or application class as well).

`@EventListener` methods can be ordered - just add `@Order` annotation to them with desired order.

More info about application event:

- [Spring Reference: Standard and Custom Events](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#context-functionality-events)
- [Baeldung: Spring Events](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events)
- [Spring blog: Better application events in Spring Framework 4.2](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2)

Comment: I use events for different purposes in this app already.  IMO events (the observer pattern as a whole really) are better suited for things that need to be propagated to several observers at once, a broadcast of sorts.  I feel like SmartLifeCycle is a more elegant solution to this specific scenario where you just need components to start and stop with the app without worrying about controlling that yourself.  I tested with a Thread.sleep inside a start() method and it does seem to honor that before starting the next one so it should suit my needs.    Hope i don't find some random side effect!

Comment: You know what, this is a great idea actually.  I have modified your suggestion a little bit but this added the huge benefit that almost everything you can think of can be triggered by a single line of code using an ApplicationEventPublisher's publish method.  This should clean up my code significantly and i'll be glad to rewrite it to accommodate this new approach.  Cheers!

Comment: @Martin I'm glad to help )

Comment: this removed over 1000 lines from my app!